# MPI implementation for Java

Tags: java, mpi, openmpi

Is there a current Java MPI implementation. I have programmed in MPI a bit, and I enjoy programming in Java. I have seen [this](http://aspen.ucs.indiana.edu/pss/HPJava/mpiJava.html) implementation in Java, but it seems dated. Is there a more up to date Java implementation that is being kept up?

Comment: mpj-express(.org) not what you're looking for?

Comment: mpj does not seem to work for os X.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look on [MPJ](http://mpj-express.org/)

You can read this [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface#Java) in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 7):

Open MPI includes a first set of java bindings on its SVN development trunk; they are slated to be part of the v1.7 release.

If you want more support than this, please post to the Open MPI user's mailing list and let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Update note: Currently the 3 most relevant implementations are [FastMPJ](http://gac.udc.es/~rreye/fastmpj/), [MPJ Express](http://mpj-express.org/) and the Java bindings of Open MPI. The three are being updated and should work on OSX, especially 100% pure Java implementations such as FastMPJ and MPJ Express.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into MPJ a while back although its still in beta its looks fairly good and is still being developed.
You mentioned that this does not work on the OSX checking the documentation there is a section that covers getting it working:-

PPC32 Mac OS X

```
  a. Edit $MPJ_HOME/bin/mpjboot and $MPJ_HOME/bin/mpjhalt
  b. Comment the line ssh $host "cd $MPJ_HOME/bin;./mpjdaemon_linux_x86_32 start;"
  c. Uncomment the line #ssh $host "cd $MPJ_HOME/bin;./mpjdaemon_macosx_ppc_32 start;"
  d. cd $MPJ_HOME/lib
  e. cp libwrapper.jnilib_macosx_ppc_32 libwrapper.jnilib
```

See: http://mpj-express.org/docs/readme/README.html#dmnvarplats

Comment: And i am running on OS X intel.

Answer (score 0):

http://fastmpj.com is another good recent alternative. You can get it by request.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a set of instructions for building and using the OpenMPI java bindings on Mac OSX to the users at open dash mpi dot org mailing list:
http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2013/01/21067.php
Hope this helps others like Milhous and I who prefer our message passing in Java !

Chuck