# Best method of having a single process distributed across a cluster

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, akka, grid-computing, condor

I'm very new to cluster computing, and wanted to know more about the various software used for cluster computing, and which is best for particular tasks. In particular, the problem I am trying to solve involves a Manager/Workers type scenario, where a single Manager is responsible for the creation of 100s to 1000s of jobs. Each job, while relatively large, must execute on a small frame-by-frame basis.  I.e. the Manager will tell each job, "advance one frame and report back to me". The execution of a single frame will be very small, so latency between the Manager and the worker machines must be very small, on the order of microseconds.

Thank you! Any information would be appreciated, even stuff that doesn't perfectly fit the scenario I described, just to give me a starting point. Some that I have researched so far are Hadoop, HTCondor, and Akka.

Comment: Don't know about the others, but, Hadoop doesn't sound like a good fit as it's for offline batch processing of big data. Doesn't quite sound like what you described.

Comment: You're right; sorry, i was very early along in the research process when i asked this. Candidates for usage are now JPPF, Akka, Twitter Storm, Open MPI, and Open DDS.

Answer (score 0):

Since communication latency is important to you, you should probably consider using [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). It's not too difficult to write simple Master/Worker programs using MPI, and it will probably give you the best performance, especially if your cluster has high performance networking, such as infiniband.

If, as it seems, you're using Java, you will have to do some research to determine a good Java/MPI package.  You'll find some suggestions here: [Java openmpi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469932/2109128).

Comment: Actually, we are using C++, just hadn't found a whole lot out there for C++ initially. OpenMPI seems great, what do you know how OpenDDS compares?

Comment: @jekelija  I can't say that I know anything about OpenDDS, but it seems to be more oriented towards enterprise computing, rather than cluster computing.  It may be worth considering, but from your description, it may be more heavy-weight than you need.